# Массивы из разных типов данных

Tags: c++, массивы

Может ли массив состоять из разных типов данных в С++?

Comment: да. Вас устроил это ответ?

Comment: @Andrey устроил.

Comment: прочитайте про std::variant и std::any, а вопрос я думаю стоит закрыть. Дубль уже 10000

Comment: В С++ невозможно объявить "массив из разных типов данных". А уж что вы имеете в виду под "состоять" - одному вам известно.

Comment: @Andrey Это будет массив из *одного* типа данных - `variant`, например...

Comment: @AnT ну например string, integer, float, bool..
В одном массиве может ли быть использовано несколько типов даних (превел пример каких више).

Comment: @Witalik: Язык С++ по определению не поддерживает никаких "массивов из разных типов данных". Поэтому такие "массивы" можно реализовать только "вручную", любым удобным для вас способом. Или воспользоваться готовой (библиотечной) реализацией.

Comment: @AnT понятно. Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: @Harry ну мы же поняли друг друга)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не может. Но можно использовать массив из типов данных, способных хранить значения разных типов. Например, массив `std::variant` или массив `union`. Также при заранее заданном количестве элементов можно использовать `std::tuple`.